# Javascript insert row into table after row with certain id

Tags: javascript

I have a table where each row has its unique id. Say there are rows with id='id25' and id='id26'. I need to insert a new row after row with id='id25'. I am using Vanilla JS without jQuery.

I have tried this:

```
var refElement = document.getElementById('id'+id);
var newrow = document.createElement("tr");
if (refElement) {
    refElement.insertBefore(newrow, refElement.nextSibling);
}
```

but it throws me an error saying 
`Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'`

The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

I know how to insert rows into top or bottom of the table but now I have an id as a reference to a particular row.

Any suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to insert into the `refElement`'s **parent**, not `refElement` itself:

```
refElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newrow, refElement.nextSibling);
// -------^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
var id = 1;
var refElement = document.getElementById('id' + id);

var newrow = document.createElement("tr");
newrow.innerHTML = "<td>new row</td>";
if (refElement) {
  refElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newrow, refElement.nextSibling);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id1"><td>refElement</td></tr>
    <tr><td>original next sibling</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

(And yes, for anyone wondering, it'll work even if the `refElement` is the last row in the table.)

---

Inserting five rows per comment:

```js
var id = 1;
var refElement = document.getElementById('id' + id);

var n, newrow;
if (refElement) {
  for (n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {
    newrow = document.createElement("tr");
    newrow.innerHTML = "<td>new row #" + n + "</td>";
    refElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newrow, refElement.nextSibling);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id1">
      <td>refElement</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>original next sibling</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note the order in which those appeared. If you want them in 0 - 4 order instead:

```js
var id = 1;
var refElement = document.getElementById('id' + id);

var n, newrow;
if (refElement) {
  for (n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {
    newrow = document.createElement("tr");
    newrow.innerHTML = "<td>new row #" + n + "</td>";
    refElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newrow, refElement.nextSibling);
    refElement = refElement.nextSibling;  // *** This is the change
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id1">
      <td>refElement</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>original next sibling</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. And if I need to insert 5 rows at a time, do I need to use some kind of a recursion here or there is some workaround for this?

Comment: @Jack: No need for recursion; when you do the `insertBefore`, `refElement.nextSibling` will be updated to refer to `newrow`, so you can just use a loop or five individual inserts. I've added a couple of examples above.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addRowAfter(rowId){
    var refElement = document.getElementById('id'+id);

    var newrow= document.createElement('tr');

    refElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newrow, refElement.nextSibling );
    return newRow;
}
```

Check this.

Comment: "Check this" answers are not useful. Say *what* you did, and *why*.